# What is the keyword used to designate a semantic field specific to a certain period of time?

Tags: semantics, lexicon

When the words 'bowler hat, shilling, bobby...' appear in a text, they tend to show that it is from a certain time period.   What's the word used to describe this sort of giveaway?
It's kind of similar to semantic field but surely there's a key word more specific to this concept?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but are you looking for something like 'era'?

Comment: Maybe _representative of an era_ is the phrase to describe the words.

Comment: A kind of "vintage," but there ought to be a better term. I don't remember of any though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a specific term but you can say that certain words *date* a text (from the American Heritage Dictionary, courtesy of wordnik.com):

> [**date**](https://www.wordnik.com/words/date)
>   transitive v. To determine the date of: date a fossil.
>   transitive v. To betray the age of: Pictures of old cars date the book.

So, in your example, you could say

> The presence of words like *shilling* and *bowler hat*<sup>1</sup> date the text to the 19th century<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>But not *bobby* which is still quite commonly used today.</sub> 
<sup>2</sup> <sub>Or, at any rate, before the 1971 [decimalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_Day).</sub>

Answer (score -1):

It tends to imply *lasting for only a **short** time*, but...

> [**transitory**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transitory) *- tending to pass away :  not persistent*

...works for me in OP's context. There's also [**transient**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transient?show=0&t=1414597429) - but to me at least, that has even stronger overtones of *existing only **briefly***.